# Immigration Clearance

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I'm an Indian citizen, travelling from Amsterdam to Thiruvananthapuram via Frankfurt. I've a flight with Lufthansa from Amsterdam to Frankfurt and Air India flight from Frankfurt to Delhi and Air India flight from Delhi to Thiruvananthapuram. Am I to complete customs formalities at Amsterdam or Frankfurt?

Answer (score 3):

The flight Amsterdam to Frankfurt will be domestic. You will cross the border and complete all customs formalities in Frankfurt

Comment: @Doc The OP says they are traveling *from* Amsterdam to Trivandrum.